# Git email notifications on pushing tags

Tags: git

In git, I am able to receive email notifications whenever I commit and push some changes. I have a post receive hook configured for this.

Is there any way to receive email notifications when a new tag is pushed to the remote repo, i.e.:

```
git push origin <tag>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `post-receive` hook gets (on its standard input) a list of all updated refs, which includes new tags. (See also the [`githooks` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)).

You can thereby easily get a list of new tags by filtering that input tags for the beginning `refs/tags/` part in refname.

Naturally, you will have you modify your `post-receive` hook for this.

Answer (score 0):

[git-multimail](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail) and its `multimailhook.announceList` variable do exactly that: send a mail for each new tag in a repository.

Note: I'm the author.